# need port to configure maven setting

Tags: maven, proxy

I know that I have a proxy that my company is using so I need to change my Maven setting. Furthermore, I ran:

```
ipconfig /all | find /i "Dns Suffix"
```

to find my proxy host, but it doesn't display my port #. I would just ask one of my co-workers the proxy #, but it's Saturday.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: I would take a look into my browser....

Comment: Thank you khmarbaise that's a good idea